# Can a storeProcecdure insert fire Trigger?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

SQL Server 2008

I have trigger defined on

TABLE_A for 'INSTEAD OF INSERT' and TABLE_B for 'INSTEAD OF INSERT'.

Both the triggers perform merge with the inserted table.

TABLE_A insert is done by user/code and is working well, trigger for insert is fired.

I have Stored procedure SP_1 inside TABLE_A TRIGGER.

SP_1 Inserts data from TABLE_A into TABLE_B based on some conditions.

But the problem is when the stored procedure (SP_1) is inserting data, the trigger on TABLE_B is not fired and the data is just inserted as it is.

So can stored procedure inserts fire triggers?

**Pseudo-code**

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtable_AInsert] ON [dbo].[TABLE_A]
Instead of INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;     

    IF exists(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN

        MERGE
             .......
             ...........
             ..............

    end

       EXEC SP_1 @employee_id
end
```

---

```
ALTER TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtableB_Insert] ON [dbo].[TABLE_B]
     Instead of INSERT
     AS
     BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;      
           IF exists(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
           BEGIN
              MERGE
                 .......
                 ...........
                 ..............
           end
     end
```

---

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_1] @employeeid int
    AS
    BEGIN   
        BEGIN TRANSACTION           

            insert into TABLE_B
                 .......
                 ...........
                 ..............
                from TABLE_A
        where employee_ID is @employeeid
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
   END
```

---

Comment: I'm immediately suspicious when I see variables and SP calls in a trigger (unless they're in some form of looping construct) - you are aware that triggers are called *once* for all rows affected (in other words, `inserted` can contain multiple rows)?

Answer (score 0):

**Yes** triggers can fired by stored procedure inserts!

But I think the problem is that you should try to use **AFTER** instead of **INSTEAD OF** triggers in this case. Becasue I can't see all of your code, but it is possible, that the insert is not done because you overrided it in the Instead Of triggers. With AFTER triggers you should have no problems with firing the second trigger.

Comment: Well It was my mistake actually. The TABLE_B MERGE was using a column that had NULL values. So the Merge using(.. = "column containing null values" and ..= ...) of merge was not working correctly and the records were always inserted. I didn't know this behavior of merge.

Comment: @Searching - it's not specific to `MERGE`. In SQL, `NULL` is never equal to `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This is too big for a comment, and needs formatting, so posting as an "answer".

Yes, triggers will fire in this case. Taking your example and slightly modifying it (note the warnings though):

```
create table Table_A (ID int not null)
go
create table Table_B (ID int not null)
GO
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_1] @employeeid int
    AS
    BEGIN   
        BEGIN TRANSACTION           

            insert into TABLE_B (ID)
            SELECT ID from TABLE_A
        where ID = @employeeid
        COMMIT TRANSACTION
   END
GO
```

Creating the triggers:

```
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtable_AInsert] ON [dbo].[TABLE_A]
Instead of INSERT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;     

    IF exists(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
    BEGIN

        MERGE
            into Table_A a
            using inserted i on a.id = i.id
            when not matched then insert (ID) values (i.id);

    end
    --Wrong code, just for example
    declare @employee_id int
    select @employee_id = ID from inserted --BAD CODE, Ignores multiple rows
       EXEC SP_1 @employee_id
end
GO
CREATE TRIGGER [dbo].[trgtableB_Insert] ON [dbo].[TABLE_B]
     Instead of INSERT
     AS
     BEGIN
       SET NOCOUNT ON;      
           IF exists(SELECT * FROM INSERTED)
           BEGIN
              MERGE
                 into Table_B b
                 using inserted i on b.id = i.id
                 when not matched then insert (ID) values (i.id+5);
           end
     end
GO
```

And executing a trial insert into `Table_A`:

```
insert into Table_A (ID) values (1),(2)
select * from Table_B
```

On my machine, at the present time, I get a final result of a single row with the value "7". Others may run this sample and get the result "6", because triggers only run once per statement, rather than once per row. But as you can see, both triggers have fired.

Answer (score 0):

As i previously mentioned in the comments    @András Ottó

```
Merge
using(... = "column with possible null values" AND 
      ... = ... AND 
      ... = ...
     )
```

of merge was not working correctly and the records were always inserted.

```
1 = 1 and E=E and NULL=NULL is not true. (of-course sql 101)
```

I have overlooked this column and did not place where clause properly to get rid of `null` values so ended up inserting all the time. Fixing that everything ended up working.

Thanks for the help Every1. Cheers

Apologies.
I'm not going to mark it answered because it is purely my mistake which was not fully mentioned in the question.